# What is the difference between alpha and lightness in HSLA color values

Tags: css, colors, alpha

What is the difference between the alpha channel value and the lightness in the HSLA? I see both these values are given to adjust the lightness of a color (or white shade in plain terms). But, by definition both seem to be different, one for opacity and the other for lightness. Can you please state the conceptual difference between these two with an example?

Comment: L is the lightness percent (100% is white, 0% is black, 50% is 'normal')

Comment: https://www.december.com/html/spec/colorhsl.html

Answer (score 1):

You can think of the **alpha channel as the transparency** of the color and the **L how much white or black** the color has (the lightness of the color).

Alpha ranges from 0% (fully transparent) to 100% (fully opaque)
Lightness ranges from 0% (black) and 100% (white).

For instance:

- hsla(0, 100%, 50%, 1) is a 100% opaque red color
- hsla(0, 100%, 90%, 1) is a 100% opaque very light pink color (because it has a high L value: lot of white)
- hsla(0, 100%, 50%, 1) is a 50% transparent red color

You can play around with it here: https://hslpicker.com/#f00

You can read about the HSL color format here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value/hsl